# JavaScript web server: Understanding blocking behavior during request handling

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, caching, async-await, event-loop

I have a web server that needs to fetch and cache around 1000 items that come from a slow api.

I would like the first request and any that hit a ttl expiration to kick off this operation, but then coninue with the request. It has other values to return, and can serve stale or null for the soon-to-be refreshed data.

I've recreated a simplified example:

```js
// ... within some handleRequest function
if (
  !cache.isFetching && 
  (!cache.isSet || cache.isStale)
) {
  // start fetch/cache, but don't block
  fetchAndCacheThatStuff();
}
// ... continue with request handling
```

I am trying to reason about how/when this will block when requests are coming in during cache refreshing:

```js
async function fetchAndCacheThatStuff() {
  cache.isFetching = true;
  for (const twoHundoIds of chunk(oneThousandIds, 200) {
    const result = await fetchItems(twoHundoIds);
    await cache.mset(result.map(mapResultToCacheEntries));
  }
  cache.isSet = true;
  cache.isStale = false;
}
```

Is there a time when the server will be waiting for a response and unable to process another incoming request?

Comment: In a JavaScript web server, blocking behavior can occur during request handling when a certain operation takes a long time to complete. This can prevent the server from processing other requests until the blocking operation is finished, leading to slower response times and potential timeouts.

For example, if a web server receives a request to read a large file, the server may need to wait for the entire file to be read before sending a response.

Answer (score 0):

The asynchronous function `fetchAndCacheStuff` will not block while waiting for a response.

From [Node.js Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1839214112) Chapter 5: Asynchronous Control Flow Patterns with Promises and Async/Await

> At each `await` expression, the execution of the function is put on hold, its state saved, and the control returned to the event loop. Once the `Promise` that has been awaited resolves, the control is given back to the async function, returning the fulfillment value of the `Promise`.